# How to set "deep structures" for Smart Contracts Tables?

Tags: smart-contract, multi-index, table

I have a table that I'm playing with that I want to have a `map` that links the id with a specific structure. I tried to use `map` and the code compiles fine, but when generating the abi file it takes forever, like it's lost in an infinite loop.

So looking into the existing contracts I found the `exchange`, which has `exchange_accounts` with a `flat_map`. The problem with it is that this smart contract has no updated abi, because it does not have all the tables of this smart contract including this `flat_map`.

Here is my actual `dao` table with `proposal` structure:

```
struct proposal {
    account_name recipient;
    asset amount;
    string description;
    uint64_t min_execution_date;
    bool executed;
    bool proposal_passed;
    uint8_t current_result;
    string proposal_hash;

    map<account_name, vote> votes;
};

// @abi table dao i64
struct dao {
    uuid id;
    account_name owner;
    uint16_t min_quorum;
    uint16_t debating_period_minutes;
    uint16_t majority_margin;

    std::vector<account_name> members;

    flat_map<uuid, proposal> proposals;

    uuid primary_key() const { return id; }
};

typedef eosio::multi_index<N(dao), dao> tb_dao;
```

Here is my abi https://github.com/leordev/eos-play/blob/master/mydao/mydao.abi

The problem is that when I run `cleos get table mydao mydao dao` the proposal structure is a messy one and does not show the proposals that I already inserted:

```
{
  "rows": [{
      "id": 1000000000,
      "owner": "leo",
      "min_quorum": 3,
      "debating_period_minutes": 4320,
      "majority_margin": 66,
      "members": [
        "flavia",
        "leo"
      ],
      "proposals": {
        "m_flat_tree": {
          "m_data": {
            "m_seq": {
              "m_holder": []
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "more": false
}
```

So my question really is, should I save deep structures inside a table like above or should I separate them in two different tables and link them, in this case, the children proposals by the parent `dao_id`?

Comment: I also have the same problem. How do you generate the abi? Did you generate it use the eosiocpp command?

Comment: try using only map instead of flat_map

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a second table to hold the proposal votes as you suggest.  This will allow you to quickly add, modify, delete, and find votes based on the indexes that you create.